# How to prevent multiple slashes during routing in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How to prevent multiple slashes during routing in Laravel ?
http://localhost/page/1 - work
and it works...
http://localhost/////page/1 - Should return 404 or redirect
This error is also on the Laravel website.
https://laravel.com////docs/5.5/errors#http-exceptions

Comment: Why do you think that should error/404? Slashes in a URL are able to double (or triple, quadruple, etc) without issue; it all depends on how the server is configured.

Comment: route file? controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, this is not a bug. A bug would imply that this is something the framework developers explicitly said shouldn't happen, but actually happens. This is mostly an undefined behaviour.

The reason this happens is because of how the request determines the current path:

In [`Request::path()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L141)

```
public function path()
{
    $pattern = trim($this->getPathInfo(), '/');
    return $pattern == '' ? '/' : $pattern;
}
```

this trims `/` from the current pathinfo to get the path. This is not an unreasonable thing to do as you would normally not want leading and trailing slashes, but this has the consequence that paths with many leading and trailing slashes will also work like for example https://laravel.com////docs/5.5/errors/////#http-exceptions

The reason this happens is because of the standard route validators in returned by [`Route::getValidators()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L1063) (specifically the UriValidator which uses `$request->path()`)

If you really must insist on "fixing" this then you can add a custom validator that checks this exact thing:

```
class MyUriValidator implements ValidatorInterface  {

    public function matches(Route $route, Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request->getPathInfo();
        return preg_match($route->getCompiled()->getRegex(), rawurldecode($path));
    }
}
```

Then you can register this extra validator in your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot() {
    Route::$validators = array_merge(Route::getValidators(), [ new MyUriValidator ]);
}
```